# Inexplicable curve shape of short circuit current measurement on synchronous machine

Tags: current-measurement, generator, short-circuit, saturation, synchronous

I'm doing some experiments on a synchronous machine with follwing data:

- nominal power: 5kVA
- nominal stator voltage: 380V phase-phase
- nominal stator current: 7.6A
- nominal frequency: 50Hz / nominal speed 1500min-1 -> 2 pole pairs
- connection stator coils: Wye
- excitation circuit connected to 1kW controllable D.C. power supply
- an external DC machine connected via the shaft drives the generator

Now I start up the generator with no-load until it reaches 1500min-1 and turn on the excitation current to get nominal voltage at the stator terminals. Then I suddenly close a short circuit with a switch at the terminals an measure the resulting current in each phase. (Circuit sketch below)
[image]

This is the result I get (1st is stator voltage between one phase and N, last 3 are the stator currents):
[image]

I'm wondering about the "strange" curve of the currents, which should in my opinion look like a sine wave. Once I saw a simillar form namely when a transformer is saturated. But my measurements look the same even when I'm doing the test with no-load voltage of 25V before the short circuit switch is closed. At this point the generator should definitely not be in saturation.

My question is now: **why do I have this unexpected short circuit current curve**? Perhaps somebody had a simillar issue.

Greetings!

Comment: What does the excitation current look like plotted against the same time frame?

Comment: It's the second curve in the figure (with the 300Hz ripple).

Comment: I can't see what it may have risen to but, could it be exhibiting a saturation profile in its waveform?